# European travelling to Caribbean Islands through USA

Tags: visas, usa, esta, caribbean

I have read that under ESTA europeans can be in the USA for up to 90 days, and we need to have a return flight to prove our way out before the time ends. I've read that if I travel to Mexico, Canada or Caribbean Islands, the ESTA period is still counting and I need to have a visa for one of those countries if I decide to stay longer. Based on this , I'm not sure if having a flight to a Caribbean Island will count as leaving the USA, and therefore do I need a flight to leave the Caribbean Islands too?

Comment: Related question that may be the answer for you, depending on how long your respective times in the US and on the island are: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/148670/do-stays-in-canada-mexico-automatically-count-towards-the-us-admission-period-un